# How to Use PHP Libraries and Create autoload Like Drupal

Tags: php, composer-php, spl-autoloader

How can i Create my own vendor/autoload with needed libraries Like Drupal
in composer directory (drupal) there many files
autoload_psr4.php
autoload_real.php
and ...

Comment: As a general rule of programming - don't do anything like drupal

Comment: It is `composer.phar` that generates the classmaps and autoloader. See: https://getcomposer.org/ As for creating your own package/repository you can use https://github.com and/or https://packagist.org to upload to and list your libraries or host your repository locally using a desired VCS (svn, git, etc) to include in your composer.json for other projects.

Comment: Composer is to PHP what NPM and Bower are to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a dependency manager called [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/). Composer takes advantage of PHP's `spl_autoload_register`, an API that allows your script to dinamically include files when missing classnames are found.

For example:

```
function appAutoloader($className)
{
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/v2/class/';

    $file = $path.$className.'.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) require_once $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('appAutoloader');

// now I can call...
new Example();
// and file "/app/v2/class/Example.php" will be required automatically
```

Composer is a powerful generator for this kind of autoloaders. You can include an external library through Composer, and that library can include other libraries as well. With a simple command, Composer will install every dependency required, in order to let you easily use the library by simply loading the "autoload.php" file.

The usage of composer is not rocket science but there's a learning curve. The best thing you can do to learn is find a library that can be installed through composer and try installing it in an existing project.

- [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/)

Comment: I dont want use Composer I just want include libraries like Guzzel or others in my project like Drupal. and generate the autoloader every time i need to include another library